# SM-T815 tablet stuck into boot loop

Tags: boot-loop, odin, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-2

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 (SM-T815), witch got into a bootloop after a android update. If the tablet reaches 0% battery and i try to plug it in, it automatically powers on into samsung logo and stays there.

### What i've tried:

- Keeping pressed the power button (up to one minute) - nothing
- Home button + vol up + power (for recovery mode) - nothing happens
- Home button + vol down + power -> Goes into a menu where i have to choose between rebooting and going download mode (rebooting goes back into samsung logo loop)

---

### If i choose download mode:

- Tried flashing original firmware with Odin3 (after finishing flashing restarts and goes back into boot loop)
- Tried firmware from different sites (I live in Romania and there are 2 types of firmware available for this country) Some of them fail at the end and others pass, but after reboot goes back to bootloop
- Kies - not compatible
- SmartSwitch - not compatible

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: in odin uncheck auto reboot, boot straight into recovery, perform factory reset

Comment: @alecxs after flashing, the tablet stays in download mode. Do i have to somehow restart it manually? Power button still doesn't work.

Comment: if your buttons broken, the only way out is flash again with auto reboot, sorry. try keep holding the recovery buttons while the reboot

Comment: @alecxs I don't mean they are broken. I mean they are not doing anything in this situation. They were working fine before and i don't think they broke just now.

Comment: if you flash the right rom and buttons working you should be able to enter recovery mode https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-t815-galaxy-tab-s2-97-lte

Comment: if this is not working you still can use it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmNOfLEbcyY

Comment: @alecxs Then maybe the problem is with the firmware. I've tried 15 firmwares from different sites. All of them get me into bootloop or fail while flashing.

Comment: improve your post with picture of the download mode screen

Comment: if bootloader is unlocked you can also flash TWRP, or if you are 100% sure device is matching flash bootloader and modem https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3719988