# Is my SM-819 (Galaxy Tab s2) salvageable?

Tags: boot-loop, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-2

I have a Galaxy Tab s2 that constantly boot loops.

It is a similar situation to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220998/sm-t815-tablet-stuck-into-boot-loop) which has no answers.

`Power`: The device enters a boot loop when turned on.
`Power + Vol up + Home`: says "booting recovery" in top left, samsung logo appears. After a couple min the screen goes blank and it enters the boot loop again.
`Power + Vol down + Home`: enters download mode which looks like this:
[image]

First thing I did was download and attempt to flash TWRP recovery, but it said FRP lock, so I can only flash stock firmwares.

I downloaded the stock version for this device (guessing the region code because I don't see it in download mode).

I used odin4 for this, and it completed successfully. The system update page came up, and at 32% said 'erasing' and restarted the device. See [Here](https://xdaforums.com/t/still-stuck-in-boot-loop-after-successfull-odin-flash.3927559/).

The suggestions said to
Reboot into recovery volume up+home+power
Wipe cache/factory reset
Reboot

However, when I attempt to reboot into recovery, it just shows the samsung logo and then goes back to a boot loop. So there's no way to do the factory reset.

I've looked at the odin options, and it has -e which is erase, which I have tried to no effect.

I have also tried heimdall but that runs into [this issue](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51062/heimdall-errors-error-failed-to-confirm-end-of-file-transfer-sequence) so I would need to build heimdall from source so I'm not sure it's worth it.

I don't want to continue debugging this if it's a hardware issue (the ROM is damaged/corrupted or something). Is there any other option I can try?

Also, it's possible the region code is incorrect, but I have no way to know since it's not showing up in the download mode. South Africa only has 2 codes, XFA and XFV. I tried both, XFA doesn't even get to the install screen, XFV gets much further so I figured that was the right one. If this is an internationally sourced device then I'm screwed.